# what does ゆげ(?) mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I'm making my way through a kid's book, and came across the sentence しゅわしゅわって、さびしいゆげが、立ってるもの。What does ゆげ or ゆげが mean here? I searched dictionaries and googled it but everything is just saying steam, which I don't think makes sense here. Is it like... metaphorical for vibes?

Comment: It's steam. What does it say before that line?

Comment: Since しゅわしゅわ is an onomatopoeia for steam, there is no doubt that it's "steam". But without context, it's hard to explain how to make sense of "lonely steam". [Please share the context](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2189/5010).

Comment: Children's books often attribute emotions to entities that wouldn't normally be thought of as having them.

Comment: The previous line is just “ぼくのせなか、どうかなってる？” which is why I'm a bit confused haha